# Match 3D vector within 4D array by interpolation?

Tags: python-3.x, vector, interpolation, 4d

I've been trying something new for the sake of learning.
I'm trying to get a wavelength from a sRGB.
I have all the sRGB to XYZ conversion and a conversion table from XYZ to wavelength - 4dimensional.

My problem remains in the last line - which seems the most complicated, at least for the non mathematician I am.
I need to find the closest XYZ position within the table conversion resembling a requested XYZ.

table looks like:

```
WL,X,Y,Z
380,0.0014,0.0000,0.0065
381,0.0015,0.0000,0.0070
382,0.0016,0.0000,0.0077
383,0.0018,0.0001,0.0085
384,0.0020,0.0001,0.0094
385,0.0022,0.0001,0.0105
386,0.0025,0.0001,0.0120
...,...,...
780,0.0000,0.0000,0.0000
```

I Use this class storing different processes - that's wip will get split:

```py
#*************
class Sounder:
#*************
  # -----------------
  def __init__(self):
  # -----------------
    self.cursor = -1

    self.__wavelengthTable = []
    with open(CONVERTER_PATH, 'r') as csvfile:
      dictReader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
      for row in dictReader:
        self.__wavelengthTable.append(row)
      csvfile.close()
    
    self.table = {
      'X': [],
      'Y': [],
      'Z': [],
      'WL': []
    }
    for row in self.__wavelengthTable:
      self.table['X'].append(row['X'])
      self.table['Y'].append(row['Y'])
      self.table['Z'].append(row['Z'])
      self.table['WL'].append(row['WL'])
```

First thing I've tried was iterating through the 4D table through its 3 XYZ coordinates:

```py
  # -------------------------------------
  def cursorIterateMatch(self, XYZArray):
  # -------------------------------------
    x = float(round(XYZArray[0], 4))
    y = float(round(XYZArray[1], 4))
    z = float(round(XYZArray[2], 4))
    # print("[{}:{}:{}]".format(x,y,z))
    found = False
    while found == False:
      if self.cursor >= self.get_tableLength():
        break
      found = self.cursorMatchAt(x, 'X')
      if found != False:
        print("x:{}".format(x))
        found = self.cursorMatchAt(y, 'Y')
        if found != False:
          print("y:{}".format(y))
          found = self.cursorMatchAt(z, 'Z')
          if found != False:
            print("z:{}".format(z))
            self.cursorReset
            return found
      # print(found)
      found = False
      self.cursorReset()
      return found

  # -----------------------------------------
  def cursorMatchAt(self, matchValue, label):
  # -----------------------------------------
    while matchValue != self.get_cursorAt(label):
      self.cursor += 1
      if self.cursor > self.get_tableLength():
        return False
    
    return self.get_cursorAt(label)

  # ----------------------------
  def get_cursorAt(self, label):
  # ----------------------------
    return self.get_tableAt(self.cursor, label)

  # ------------------------------------
  def get_tableAt(self, rowIdx,  label):
  # ------------------------------------
    if rowIdx >= self.get_tableLength():
      return False
    return self.__wavelengthTable[rowIdx][label.upper()]
```

Obviously it did not work, for the XYZ I get never perfectly matches a position.

So I started checking for nearest position functions, and tried this:

```py
  # -----------------------------
  def aproxMatch(self, XYZArray):
  # -----------------------------
    x = float(round(XYZArray[0], 4))
    y = float(round(XYZArray[1], 4))
    z = float(round(XYZArray[2], 4))
    # print("[{}:{}:{}]".format(x,y,z))
    xfound = self.findNearestAt(x, 'X')
    yfound = self.findNearestAt(y, 'Y')
    zfound = self.findNearestAt(z, 'Z')
    print("[{}:{}:{}]".format(xfound,yfound,zfound))
    
    mx = max([xfound, yfound, zfound])
    mn = min([xfound, yfound, zfound])
    diff = mx - mn

    if diff > 5:
      return False
   
    return (xfound + yfound + zfound)/3

  # -----------------------------------------
  def findNearestAt(self, matchValue, label):
  # -----------------------------------------
    array = np.asarray(self.table[label])
    idx = (np.abs(array - matchValue)).argmin()
    return idx
```

But obviously that's not working since it is still too strict. Then I tried on the interpolation side of things and I must say... I'm lost.

I get the global concept of interpolation but I can't seem to find how to apply the good interpolation type. So I just need someone to tell me which one I should use for this problem.

I'm not asking for a solution, I just need an advice on where to search - since interpolation seems a whole new cosmos of information I've found stuff to "mutate" object or to approximate in-between values from a pool. But I don't get how you could get an approximated position of a 3d vector within a 4d array.

So to resume: I just need a direction within the interpolation world, to understand how to get 4th dimension within 4d array with the closest match from a 3d vector.

Answer (score 0):

First, converting from RGB to WaveLength seems to require a step of normalizing the RGB value to a set intensity, then doing a lookup of the normalized value and answering the pair of the wavelength and intensity values.

That is

```
( wavelength( norm(R, G, B) ), intensity(R, G, B) )
```

That is based on noting that proportionately similar RGB values should map to the same wavelength.  Similar values have the same *color*, just at different intensities.

That suggests that the wavelength table also be normalized.  And, that black is a special case where the wavelength is not defined and the intensity is zero.

Second, shouldn't `findNearestAt` compare distances?  Note that the comparison can use the square of the distance, which would be much faster for doing the comparisons.

Third, if the wavelength table is normalized, then the table values (and the lookup value) all fit on the surface of a three dimensional sphere.  Since the table values are ordered (by wavelength), the points should march across the sphere in an orderly fashion, although probably not in a simple line.  That orderly placement very possibly could be used to fashion a quick lookup function.

Comment: As a side note: The RGB value is a much more accurate way to model light than the wavelength value.  An RGB value provides a coarse distribution of a spectrum.  So far as manipulating and combining color values, working with the distribution should be a lot more accurate than trying to manipulate the wavelengths.  Check out this for a lot of fascinating information: http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_35.html

Comment: if you want to see the whole project [here it is](https://github.com/Moltenhead/The-Sound-of-Images). The sRGB is already "filtered" in a fashion I found on the web - vision is far cooler than expected. You can check the `modules.ColorSpace.py` to see the "conversion".
You're surely right on the `nearestAt` function I'll check that out once it will be working.
And well that's the look-up function I'm trying to find.
The goal is to find `ColorHz.toTHz().down40Oct()` to produce a sound for each wavelength, so yeah RGB is more precise but don't fit the purpose. And thanks for the cool doc. :)

Comment: Yeah, color is great.  I started with a physical understanding of light only to discover that color and color perception involves a lot more stuff.

Comment: Other things I was wondering about: Neither black nor white map to a wavelength, and factoring out intensity misses how light or dark a color is.  A whiteness level might need to be subtracted to determine the proper wavelength.  Maybe, light intensity could return as sound volume?  And could lightness/darkness show up as "noise" in the sound?  That would map an "impure" color to "impure" sound.

Comment: Interesting project.  Following the project links, the pages that show how to transform between color spaces probably won't help, since those are a different sort of transformation.  Also, the table of wavelength to RGB values is a little misleading.  That table is showing (I think) a usual human eye's response to wavelength.  780 is all zeros because the human eye doesn't see light that has a wavelength of 780 nm or longer.